# Matrix Transformation of a Line $y=mx+c$

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

> By first finding an expression for $x$ and $y$ variables in terms of the corresponding image $X$ and $Y$ variables, find the image of the line $y = 2x - 7$ under the transformation given by $M = \left(\begin{matrix}1 & -3 \\ -3 & 2\end{matrix}\right)$.

Comment: Maybe use $\pmatrix{X\\Y}=\mathbf{M}\pmatrix{x\\y}$

Answer (score 3):

$\begin{pmatrix}1&&-3\\-3&&2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x\\y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}x-3y\\-3x+2y\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}X\\Y\end{pmatrix}.$

So, if $y=2x-7,$ then $X=x-3y=-5x+21$ and $Y=-3x+2y=x-14$.

Now can you find a linear relationship between $X$ and $Y$?

(What's $X+5Y$?)

Answer (score 1):

1) Take 2 (arbitrary) points on the initial line, for example $(0,-7)$ and $(1,-5)$,

2) Get their images by $M$ : $P_1=(X_1,Y_1)=(-21,14)$ and $P_2=(X_2,Y_2)=(16,-13)$ resp.

3) Then use a formula giving the equation of the line passing through two points :

$$\dfrac{Y-Y_1}{X-X_1}=\dfrac{Y_2-Y_1}{X_2-X_1}$$

(expressing identity of slopes for straight lines $P_1P$ and $P_2P_1$ where $P=(x,y)$ is the generic point of common straight line).

Answer (score 1):

1) Write the equation in matrix form:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & - 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} = 7. $$

2) Modify the equation so it includes $\begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1 & -3 \\ -3 & 2\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$:

$$ \left[ \begin{pmatrix} 2 & - 1 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}1 & -3 \\ -3 & 2\end{pmatrix}^{-1} \right] \left[ \begin{pmatrix}1 & -3 \\ -3 & 2\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix} \right] = 7 $$

3) Simplify:

$$ \begin{pmatrix} -\frac17 & -\frac57 \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} X \\ Y \end{pmatrix} = 7. $$

So we have $X + 5Y = -49$.